# Haxe typing expr macro position

Tags: macros, haxe

Trying to get the type of an expression `e` with seems to use the current position rather than the position in `e`:

```
Context.typeof(e)
```

I have a macro that is called from *Foo.hx*, but during that macro I need to type an `Expr` that is in *Bar.hx* (and thus can access all of Bar's imports). How can I use Bar's imports/variables/etc? Whatever position is in `e.pos` (and all the descendants of `e.pos`), `Context.typeof()` uses the current position (in bar).

Is there any way around this?